# Filtering nested attributes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, nested-attributes

My application is composed of `Category` that `has_many products`. Category as well as products have a publication date.

The show page of category display the product from that category.

The show and index actions of Category_controller are very simple (published is a scope):

```
def index
    @categories = Category.published
end

def show
    @categories = Category.find(params[:id])
    unless @categories.datepublication <= Time.now
        redirect_to categories_path
    end
end
```

As you can see it display published category and redirect you to category index when you are being too  curious for your own sake.

Now it would be great to display only published products in the show view of a category. I do not know how to do that except with a if in the view, but it seems to me that filtering elements is not the job of the view. What is the correct MVC way of filtering a nested element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain scopes, even through associations. From your example I gather that your categories have a publication date but your products also have their own publication date, is that right?

In that case you could set up a scope on your products similar to the one you have on your categories and just use it the same way, i.e.:

```
@products = @category.products.published
```

Then whether you want to preload the @products instance variable in the controller or just use @category.products.published in the view is up to you. If the application is simple enough I usually just use the scoped query in the view myself.

Comment: Is there a way to keep a stupid generic view where i loop around @category.products and not around @products? With products being filtered of course. My real app use quite a lot of partials.

Comment: Yep, that's fine. Just use the scoped method in your view, so for example: `<%= @category.products.published do |product| %><%= product.name %><% end -%>`

Answer (score 1):

This is the job of the ORM (also for categories)

```
 begin
   @category = Category.published.find(params[:id])
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
   redirect_to categories_path unless @category
 end

 @products = @category.products.published
```